# GitHub pages test build fails with exit code 15

Tags: docker, jekyll, travis-ci, github-pages

The GitHub pages build for [this repository](https://github.com/dmcpatrimonio/adaptive-construction/pull/4)'s `dev` branch started failing for no apparent reason. The Jekyll CI test builds all the required gems, then throws `[error] Process completed with exit code 15`, for which I could not find a definition.

Inspecting the [offending commit](https://github.com/dmcpatrimonio/adaptive-construction/pull/4/commits/79682fa3e7a8412599eac2bab89a81699708a7a4), I could not find any code changes that should cause a build failure when it previously succeeded.

EDIT:

Though the [test workflow](https://github.com/dmcpatrimonio/adaptive-construction/blob/dev/.github/workflows/jekyll.yml) fails, the production GitHub pages build itself succeeds. I have not changed the workflow code, however.

Comment: I am having the same problem, the issue seems to be with bundle install step

Comment: Also experiencing this issue on Github Actions. Seems to be a problem with the latest image, as others have also reported downgrading to 3.8 as a workaround (which also worked for me). [1](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/issues/272#issuecomment-622507643) [2](https://github.com/opendocsg/opendoc-formsg-faq/pull/62/files) [3](https://github.com/envygeeks/jekyll-docker/issues/269)

Comment: Using the jekyll:3.8.5 image worked for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your site is already built by CI, you can add a .nojekyll file at the root of your code to instruct gh-pages not to generate but just publish you site.

You can also check this [Help guide](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites).

This link describe [jekyl for github-pages](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/)

Comment: Thank you. However, I think this might be a problem with the [CI test workflow](https://github.com/dmcpatrimonio/adaptive-construction/blob/dev/.github/workflows/jekyll.yml) and not with the code itself --- though I haven't touched this workflow, some GitHub-side update might have broken it. My build tests using this wf have started to fail across all of my repositories, but the GitHub pages build itself succeeds if I push to the master branch.